# Are there any JS objects for which IsCallable is false but IsConstructor is true?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, language-lawyer

The ECMAScript specification function [IsCallable](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-iscallable) returns true iff its argument has a [[Call]] internal method.  It is used in several places in the specification, such as in the definition of  [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring).

There is a similar specification function [IsConstructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-isconstructor) which returns true iff its argument has a [[Construct]] internal method.

Some JS objects, including most built-in functions such as `escape` are callable but not constructible.  **Are there any which are constructible but not callable?**

Note that both user-defined and built-in classes throw `TypeError` when called as ordinary functions, but are still callable per the definition of IsCallable, as can be determined by seeing if `Array.prototype.toString` will attempt to use them as the implementation of `join`:

```js
// {} is not callable, so toString falls back to Object.prototype.toString:
console.log('null:', Array.prototype.toString.apply({join: {}}));
```

```js
// WeakMap is callable (but throws TypeError):
console.log('null:', Array.prototype.toString.apply({join: WeakMap}));
```

```js
// User-defined classes also callable:
console.log('null:', Array.prototype.toString.apply({join: class Foo {}}));
```

Comment: possible cases: [`Image` and `Option`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147221/1048572). There's nothing in the spec that would prevent such a thing from existing, but it would be very weird indeed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a constructor always a function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10393858/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restatement: Is it possible for an object X to return `true` for `IsConstructor(X)` but `false` for `IsCallable(X)`? I.e., is it possible for an object X to have a `[[Construct]]` internal method but not have a `[[Call]]` internal method?

The ECMAScript spec isn't as clear-cut on this point as it could be.

(1)
[6.1.7.2 "Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots"](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) says:

> A *function object* is an object that supports the [[Call]] internal method. A *constructor* (also referred to as a *constructor function*) is a function object that supports the [[Construct]] internal method.

From this we can conclude that if such an object X *does* exist, it is clearly not a 'function object' and thus also not a 'constructor'. I.e. `IsConstuctor(X)` would return `true` for an object that isn't deemed a 'constructor', which would be odd.

(2)
Note that in the clause that defines `IsConstructor`, the preamble says that it determines whether its argument "is a function object with a [[Construct]] internal method", but the algorithm doesn't have an explicit check that the argument is a function object. This suggests that (the spec-writer thought that) having a [[Construct]] internal method is sufficient to guarantee that the argument is a function object, i.e. that it has a [[Call]] internal method.

(3)
The only point to having a `[[Construct]]` internal method is to invoke it in [the `Construct` abstract operation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-construct). Similar to point (2), the preamble says that the operation "is used to call the [[Construct]] internal method of a function object", but the algorithm doesn't explicitly check that `F` is a function object.

So I believe the answer is that, while the spec doesn't *explicitly* say that such objects can't exist, it fairly strongly implies/assumes that they don't.

---

UPDATE (2018-05-22):

[6.1.7.2 "Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots"](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) has now been modified to say (emphasis mine):

> A *function object* is an object that supports the [[Call]] internal method. A *constructor* is an object that supports the [[Construct]] internal method. **Every object that supports [[Construct]] must support [[Call]]**; that is, every constructor must be a function object. Therefore, a constructor may also be referred to as a *constructor function* or *constructor function object*.

Answer (score 3):

No, it’s not possible to create something that’s constructible but not callable. Everything that defines a [[Construct]] in the spec is a function except for proxies, which only have [[Construct]] when their target also does ([9.15.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-construct-argumentslist-newtarget)).

> A Proxy exotic object only has a [[Construct]] internal method if the initial value of its [[ProxyTarget]] internal slot is an object that has a [[Construct]] internal method.